# Print hash of arrays as colums to file

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, printing

Is there a way to print a hash of arrays to a file with the keys to the hash as header and the values of the arrays as tab ( or anything else ) delimited columns ?

My last try was something like this:

```
foreach my $key(sort keys %outHash){

    my $temp1 = join ("\n",@{$outHash{$key}});

    my $temp2 = $key."\n".$temp1;

    print OUTPUT "$temp2\t";
    print OUTPUT "\n";

}
```

Which produces just horrible output.
Any help would be greatly appreciated ! 
Thank you.

Comment: We need some more information about your source data to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - you have a hash of arrays, that you want to print in columns.

To do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %test = (
   a => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
   b => [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
);

my @header = sort keys %test;

print join (",", @header), "\n";
while ( map {@$_} values %test ) {
   my @row;
   push( @row, shift @{ $test{$_} } // '' ) for @header;
   print join (",", @row ), "\n";
}
```

But you'd probably better off with a different data structure, that's got your data organise row-wise, and iterate row by row using a hash slice instead.

Comment: Thank both of you very much ! Both approaches worked perfectly. I actually thought about organizing the data differently but the main problem is that I need to group something and hash of arrays was the best approach to solve this. I thought about turning the HoA into a 2D Matrix but the thought of trying to transpose it in perl frightened me a little bit ( rather new to perl ).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my %out_hash = (
    a => [1,2,3],
    b => [3,4,5],
);

my @keys = sort keys %out_hash;
say join "\t", @keys;
my $N = 3;
for my $i (0 .. ($N-1)) {
    my @row;
    for my $key (@keys) {
        push @row, $out_hash{$key}->[$i];
    }
    say join "\t", @row;
}
```

**Output**:

```
a   b
1   3
2   4
3   5
```

Comment: ... it's almost creepy how similar that code is, to the point where we've both picked similar example data independently...

Comment: yes... it happens sometimes :) you provided a more general solution though, allowing for variable row lengths